# subdividing the rows of data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two columns data as

```
5   8.2
15  7.4
18  3.2
25  9.1
```

I want to subdivide each rows values with 2
so that data will be

```
2.5  4.1
2.5  4.1
7.5  3.7
7.5  3.7
9.0  1.6
9.0  1.6
12.5 4.55
12.5 4.55
```

Then i want to subdivide each row values by 10  and i want to write the same to a file.
I tried the below code but it doesnot do the same thing what i expect.Hope experts may help me. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('two_column.txt') 
data=data/2
data=data/10
np.savetxt('output.txt',data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a DataFrame,you can replicate the rows with [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) by `N`:

```
N = 2

out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(N)].div(N) # or .div(10*N) if wanted
```

Output:

```
      0     1
0   2.5  4.10
0   2.5  4.10
1   7.5  3.70
1   7.5  3.70
2   9.0  1.60
2   9.0  1.60
3  12.5  4.55
3  12.5  4.55
```

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
out = np.repeat(df.to_numpy(), N, axis=0)/N

# or with an array A as input
out = np.repeat(A, N, axis=0)/N
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2.5 ,  4.1 ],
       [ 2.5 ,  4.1 ],
       [ 7.5 ,  3.7 ],
       [ 7.5 ,  3.7 ],
       [ 9.  ,  1.6 ],
       [ 9.  ,  1.6 ],
       [12.5 ,  4.55],
       [12.5 ,  4.55]])
```

Comment: I think OP wants `repeat(N)`?

Comment: error:   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: i am taking input as data=np.loadtxt('two_column.txt')

Comment: Then you have strings, add `.astype(float)` right before `div(N)`

Comment: Can you provide the content of `two_column.txt`?

Comment: already provided it is on the top of my question 5   8.2
15  7.4
18  3.2
25  9.1

Comment: when i change as suggested  valueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Not sure what you did, but `np.repeat(data, N, axis=0)/N` works for me with the top block as input for `np.loadtxt`